# Is it reasonable to have a zero mean Gaussian prior for the coefficients of an AR(p) process, assuming it is stable?

Tags: bayesian, stochastic-processes, prior, autoregressive, optimization

I wanna perform **parameter estimation** of an underlying **AR(p) process** given some data. Let's say it's stable.
For example an AR(2) process is stable when the conditions

$a_2 - a_1 < 1,$

$a_2 + a_1 < 1,$ and

$-1 < a_2$

are all satisfied by the AR coefficients $a_1, a_2$. Since this is a small triangle in the $a_1$-$a_2$ space which contains the origin (see e.g. the middle of this [blog post](http://davegiles.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/when-is-autoregressive-model.html) for picture), I was thinking whether putting a **Gaussian prior** is valid.
(Actually, the mean is (0, -$\frac13$), which is only *close* to zero.)

Since I kinda think this is reasonable for order 2, and there are other (more complicated) formulas for the coefficients of a higher order processes, I wonder if this is true in general.

Comment: Do you plan to set the Gaussian prior restricted to the triangle? We use a uniform prior over that set in our book [Bayesian essentials](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/wp-admin/link.php?action=edit&link_id=41).

Comment: Well, I wasn't plannning to. I would use the full Gaussian and not the truncated since it's easier to calculate with. But I guess both are better than _no prior_ at all...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to set priors on stationary AR(p) processes is to go via the partial correlations, which don't have to satisfy difficult constraints.

We did some version of this in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.4630v2.pdf --- NB: not the newest version on arXiv. It was cut for space) and it worked pretty well.

Using Gaussians truncated to ensure stationarity is an old trick (I think it was Chib who suggested it) but for the cost of a Jacobian transformation it doesn't seem really worth the trouble...

Hope this helps!

Dan